# How much time do I need at Copenhagen airport?

Tags: trains, airports, copenhagen

I will be travelling to Copenhagen and from there to Helsingborg on 1 June and back again on 3 June.

How much time do I need at Copenhagen airport to get off the plane, fetch my baggage and go on the train from the Copenhagen airport railway station to Helsingborg?

And when coming back, how much time do I need to get off the train at Copenhagen airport railway station, check in and check my luggage in, go through security control and get on the plane?

Currently I have reserved two hours to get from the plane to the train, and when coming back, three and a half hours to get from the train to the plane. Will this be enough, or do I need more time?

More information was requested, so I'm editing my question. I'm Finnish and travelling from/to Helsinki. The flights are in early afternoon, the flight to Copenhagen arrives at 15:10 and the flight back leaves at 14:45.

Comment: You basically asked the same question yesterday.

Comment: Where are you arriving from?

Comment: We need a lot more information to give good answers. Some examples: What's your nationality, where are you arriving from/going to (by plane) and what time of day will you travel.

Comment: More details were added.

Answer (score 1):

That's plenty in both directions. I'd recommend pre-buying the train ticket online since lines at the ticket machine in Copenhagen airport can be quite long.